# Url to pdf using wkhtmltopdf.exe at server side

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

Back few days i'm trying to make a web application that convert url to pdf. Finally i have done this with the help of wkhtmltopdf.exe
My class code is given below

```
public class PDFGenerator
{
    public static string HtmlToPdf(string pdfOutputLocation, string outputFilenamePrefix, string[] urls,
        string[] options = null,
        string pdfHtmlToPdfExePath = "C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf.exe")
    {
        string urlsSeparatedBySpaces = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            //Determine inputs
            if ((urls == null) || (urls.Length == 0))
                throw new Exception("No input URLs provided for HtmlToPdf");
            else
                urlsSeparatedBySpaces = String.Join(" ", urls); //Concatenate URLs

            string outputFolder = pdfOutputLocation;
            string outputFilename = outputFilenamePrefix + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss-fff") + ".PDF"; // assemble destination PDF file name

            var p = new System.Diagnostics.Process()
            {
                StartInfo =
                {
                    FileName = pdfHtmlToPdfExePath,
                    Arguments = ((options == null) ? "" : String.Join(" ", options)) + " " + urlsSeparatedBySpaces + " " + outputFilename,
                    UseShellExecute = false, // needs to be false in order to redirect output
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    RedirectStandardError = true,
                    RedirectStandardInput = true, // redirect all 3, as it should be all 3 or none
                    WorkingDirectory = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(outputFolder)
                }
            };

            p.Start();

            // read the output here...
            var output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            var errorOutput = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

            // ...then wait n milliseconds for exit (as after exit, it can't read the output)
            p.WaitForExit(60000);

            // read the exit code, close process
            int returnCode = p.ExitCode;
            p.Close();

            // if 0 or 2, it worked so return path of pdf
            if ((returnCode == 0) || (returnCode == 2))
                return outputFolder + outputFilename;
            else
                throw new Exception(errorOutput);
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            throw new Exception("Problem generating PDF from HTML, URLs: " + urlsSeparatedBySpaces + ", outputFilename: " + outputFilenamePrefix, exc);
        }
    }
}
```

and my button click event code is given below

```
//Create PDF from a single URL
    var pdfUrl = PdfGenerator.PDFGenerator.HtmlToPdf(pdfOutputLocation: "~/PDFs/",
        outputFilenamePrefix: "GeneratedPDF",
        urls: new string[] { "http://news.bbc.co.uk" });

    //Create PDF from multiple URLs
    pdfUrl = PdfGenerator.PDFGenerator.HtmlToPdf(pdfOutputLocation: "~/PDFs/",
        outputFilenamePrefix: "GeneratedPDF",
        urls: new string[] { "http://www.google.co.uk", "http://news.bbc.co.uk" });
```

all code is working properly and saving pdf in my PDFs code. But i have 2 questions:

1. This code is not working when i host my website because `C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf.exe` executing error. Is any dll library avail for wkhtmltopdf?
2. When i run this code pdf saved in silent mode. I want to know that is this possible to save pdf with save dialog or ask user to folder location where they want to save pdf?
   Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

1. Place your "wkhtmltopdf.exe" in your project folder, so that it can be easily accessible to your application. There might be some access related issues if you have your .exe file in 'C' folder. Try this, it worked for me.